# Why is a Flerken so dangerous?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

I watched *Captain Marvel*. I remember Talos calling the cat a Flerken. But I also remember some report on the animal as being very dangerous. Why is a cat with tentacles in it's mouth so dangerous?

Comment: ....because tentacles can easily eat you alive? :P

Comment: Because.. it capable of swallowing an infinity stone and eat people in a single gulp 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why is an animal that can eat the Tesseract, a container for an Infinity Stone (Space Stone)...

...and eat 4 or so armed Kree soldiers without taking a scratch like it's nothing...

...dangerous you ask? Don't know, no reason. And to a lesser extent [Goose also takes Fury's eye and gives him what looks to be an infection of sorts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll5pKBPYWR8).

---

Also note this snippet from Marvel's official website.

> Perhaps the most shocking aspect of the Flerkens are the massive tentacles that emerge from their mouths which can devour a person or an alien whole in moments. Note that Fury, in "Captain Marvel," was still able to hold on to Goose after that happened. That’s because the body of the Flerkens contain pocket dimensions with enough space to store entire universes. Therefore, the weight of an alien body wouldn’t be present in a Flerken stomach.
>
> <sub>[Marvel, Captain Marvel: What The Flerk Is A Flerken?](https://www.marvel.com/articles/movies/captain-marvel-what-the-flerk-is-a-flerken)</sub>

If that isn't enough for you to think a Flerken is dangerous I don't know what is.

Comment: They're bigger on the inside!  Must be from Gallifrey...

Comment: So how big is the pocket dimension? The size of a universe or just big?